# Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 2103

Tags: silverlight, unhandled

I have reflected all the namespaces and now getting error: Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2103

Comment: I have shorted out this issue.

Answer (score 4):

There are three thing to short out this issue for sure:

(1) Check the Startup Object in the properties is correct.
Right Click on Client Poject > Properties > Startup Object

(2) Be sure to explicitly add your Silverlight project as a dependent project for your web project, this is not done by default.
:Right click on Solution (not on the individual project) > Properties > Project Dependencies > Select Web Project under Project & Check Silverlight Client Project under Depends on. > Apply > Ok.

(3) Re-add your Silverlight project under the Silverlight Applications in the web project's properties..
:Right Click on Web Project > Properties > Silverlight Applications > Click on Add & Select Silverlight Client Project Under Project.

Answer (score 3):

After moving to a new Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 setup, I had the same problem.

The solution in my case was to enable "Static Content" within Windows Features. ([Source: dundas.com](http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard5.UnhandledErrorSilverlight2103.ashx))

It is found in the "IIS | WWW | Common HTTP Features" section:

[image: Windows Features on/off - IIS - WWW - Common HTTP Features]